# C++ to javascript conversion

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

The question I'm doing is:

> **Write a JavaScript program to create a function which returns the number of times required to replace a given number with the sum of its digits until it converts to a single digit number. Like if given number is 123, number of times required to convert it into a single digit number is 1 (1+2+3=6). Your output code should be in the format console.log("Result is ", variableName)**

I could not find the solution to this problem so I googled it and found this [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-times-number-can-replaced-sum-digits-contains-one-digit/).

The code on this page is in C/C++ ,Java etc...I took the C++ code and tried to convert it to javascript myself and this is the result:

```
var num=prompt("Enter a number");
var a= num.toString();

function test(x) 
{var temporary_sum = 0, count = 0; 

while (x.length() > 1) 
{ 
    temporary_sum = 0; 

    // computing sum of its digits 

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) 
        temporary_sum += ( x[ i ] - '0' ) ; 

    // converting temporary_sum into string 
    // x again .

    x = temporary_sum.toString() ; 

    // increase the count 

    count++; 
 } 

 return count; 
} 

var output = test(a) ;
console.log("Result is: ", output);
```

This code does not give any output at all. How can I fix this? Is there a better way to do this question?

Comment: The code [works](https://repl.it/repls/KindheartedSlategrayOutlier) for me if I take the parens off of `x.length` (it's a property, not a method). The answer is incorrect as far as I can tell, but the code runs and gives an output.

Comment: Your code should throw an error because `x.length` is not a function. Do you not see an error in the console?

Comment: the console stays completely empty but that might just be some issue with the website I'm practicing this on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a better way to do that using recursion. And `reduce`

```js
function test(x,count=0){
  if(String(x).length === 1) return count;
  let sum = String(x).split('').reduce((ac,a) => Number(a) + ac,0);
  return test(sum,++count);
} 
console.log(test(123))  //1
console.log(test(456))  //2
console.log(test(99999999999))  //3
```

Comment: _"Here is a better way to do that"_ Can you clearly define _"better"_? How is "better" objectively measured?

Comment: @guest271314 By better I mean its clean and than regular `for` or `while` loop

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? What is the issue with "regular `for` or `while` loop"?

Comment: @guest271314 I mean recursion is better than 1)creating a variable `temporary_sum` 2)then using this ugly thing `for (var i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) `3) And then creating a nested `for` loop is `while` loop.I can be wrong

Comment: _"I mean recursion is better than 1)creating a variable `temporary_sum` 2)then using this ugly thing `for (var i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)` 3) And then creating a nested for loop is while loop."_ That is your opinion.  How is "better" _objectively_ measured?

Comment: @guest271314 actually I don't what **objectively measured** mean. English is not my mother tounge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188864/discussion-between-maheer-ali-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your last question - yes, there is a better way to do this question. You want to use recursion. You can also split the string on '' to convert its digits into an array, and you want to use parseInt to turn it back into a number.

Answer (score 0):

I will use a different approach (I don't say it would be better). First, I will skip the mapping from `number` to `string` and wraps the logic that sums the digits of some number into a function called `sumDigits()`. This way you have a resusable method you can use for other purposes later. The second step is to define your `test` function using the previously created `sumDigits` mainly using the `while` loop you already have but testing with another condition and generalized to accept also integer negative numbers:

```js
const sumDigits = (num) =>
{
    let sum = 0;

    while (num)
    {
        sum += num % 10, num = Math.floor(num / 10);
    }

    return sum;
}

const test = (num) =>
{
    let counter = 0;
    num = Math.abs(num);

    while (num >= 10)
    {
       num = sumDigits(num), counter++;
    }

    return counter;
}

console.log(test(123));
console.log(test(456));
console.log(test(-789));
```